# How to handle accents with enscript?

Tags: character-encoding, enscript, symbol-table

I cannot figure out how to handle accents with `enscript` when converting a txt into a pdf:

```
echo "élisée" | enscript  -o - -X <encoding> | ps2pdf - output.pdf
```

I tried all possible encoding but none are leading to the proper result.

I guess I should add a iconv at the first stdout

---

List of enscript encoding that I have tried:

- 88592
- 88593
- 88594
- 88595
- 88597
- 88599
- 885910
- ascii
- asciifise
- asciidkno
- ibmpc
- mac
- vms
- hp8
- koi8
- ps
- pslatin1

Answer (score 11):

The usual character encoding in Linux is UTF-8; however, `enscript` does not support UTF-8. You need to convert the text to an encoding supported by enscript, such as ISO 8859-1:

```
echo "élisée" | iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 | enscript -X 88591 -o - | ps2pdf - output.pdf
```

Or you could use a text-to-PostScript converter which accepts UTF-8 encoded text, such as `paps`.

Comment: Using `iso-8859-1//TRANSLIT` instead of plain `iso-8859-1` may save you some `iconv: illegal input sequence at position XX` errors.